# Scala: Set a value based on parameter-type

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I have a beginner question related to `scala implicit`:

```
class Box[T](implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) {
  var value = None: Option[Any]

  def pickValueUsingTypeOfT : Unit = {
    val list = List("string", 1, new myClass(1D) )
    println(s"type of  has type arguments $tag")
    //value = Some ( find right element from the 'list' )
  }
}

class myClass(double: Double) {}


object Setter {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val n: Box[String] = new Box[String]
    n.pickValueUsingTypeOfT
  }
}
```

The objective is to set the `value` according to type of `T`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need reflection for such resolution. You need [typeclass](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html) (like the `Numeric`).

```
trait Foo[T] {
  def aProp: String
  def aFun(v: T): Int
}

object Foo {
  // default instances

  object StrFoo extends Foo[String] {
    // for T = String
    val aProp = "Bar"
    def aFun(v: String) = v.length
  }

  object LongFoo extends Foo[Long] {
    val aProp = "Lorem"
    def aFun(v: Long) = v.toInt
  }
}
```

So your function can be defined as following.

```
def pickValueUsingTypeOfT[T](implicit resolved: Foo[T]) = ???
```

Then it can be used for default instances:

```
pickValueUsingTypeOfT[String].aProp
pickValueUsingTypeOfT[Long].aFun(123L)
```

If it's called for unsupported type, the compiler will find this issue and help you (which better than runtime reflection):

```
pickValueUsingTypeOfT[Byte] // compiler error
```

Extra instances can be defined.

```
val localV = "value"

implicit val byteFoo: Foo[Byte] = new Foo[Byte] {
  def aProp: String = localV
  def aFun(v: Byte) = v.toInt * 10
}

pickValueUsingTypeOfT[Byte].aFun(456.toByte)
// now is ok with byteFoo
```